# Prove that if $H \unlhd G$, then $C_{G}(H) \unlhd G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

The question is: Prove that if $H \unlhd G$, then $C_{G}(H) \unlhd G$, where $C_{G}(H)$ is the centralizer of the group $H$ in $G$.

What I need to show: $gC_{G}(H)=C_{G}(H)g$, which is equivalent to (1) $gC_{G}(H) \subseteq C_{G}(H)g$ and (2) $C_{G}(H)g \subseteq gC_{G}(H)$.

(1) Let $gc \in gC_{G}(H)$, where $c \in C_{G}(H)$. Note that $gc=gcg^{-1}g$. So it's enough to show that $gcg^{-1} \in C_{G}(H)$. Note that $c=gh=hg$ (because $c \in C_{G}(H)$). And note that
$c=gh=hg \iff gcg^{-1}=gghg^{-1}=ghgg^{-1}$. And $ghgg^{-1}=ghe=gh$. The last one ($gh$) is equal to $c$ by construction. Then, $gcg^{-1}=ghgg^{-1}=gh=c$. Therefore, $gcg^{-1} \in C_{G}(H)$.

My doubt is: is this proof right? Am I missing something? Can I really use the same $g$'s in both cases: $g\in G$ and $g \in C_{G}(H)$?. I think so, cus it's the same group $G$ in both, but I need some validation here.

I know the proof of (2) is similar to the (1). So if (1) is right, (2) will also be right.

Comment: Why is $c = hg$?  $c$ is just an element of the centralizer of $H$ (in $G$), so $c$ commutes with any element of $h$, but that's all we know about $c$.  (Of course, $c$ *can* be written as a product of an element of $g$ by a chosen $h \in H$ because, as $g$ ranges over $G$, $gh$ ranges over all of $G$ so is $c$ for one choice of $g$.)

Comment: @EricTowers That's why I wrote $c=hg=hg$, because it's the definition of centralizer and because it was a smart way to write it that would eventually help me with the proof. So my doubt remains: is the proof valid? Idk if I can use the same element $g$ in the cases I described in the question above (g in the centralizer and g in the group G).

Comment: Hint: It is a lot easier to prove that it is invariant under conjugation, rather than trying to prove that left and right cosets are equal. To do that, show that for any group $G$, any subgroup $K$, and any element $g\in G$,  $gC_G(K)g^{-1} = C_G(gKg^{-1})$.

Comment: ... then your justification "because $c \in C_G(H)$" is bogus.  Fix an $h \in H$.  *Every* element of $G$ is a $gh$ for some element in $g$, not just elements of $C_G(H)$.  And while it is true that for all $c \in C_G(H)$, $ch = hc$, the *definition* of centralizer does not require $gh = hg$ when $hg \in C_G(H)$ -- this is a derived property that we must prove separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $ch=hc$ for every $h\in H$ and $g\in G$, then $(gcg^{-1})h=
gc(g^{-1}hg)g^{-1}=g(g^{-1}hg)cg^{-1}=h(gcg^{-1})$ because $g^{-1}hg\in H$. Hence $gC_G(H)g^{-1}\subseteq C_G(H)$ and $C_G(H)$ is normal.

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ is normal,  then the centralizer of $H$ is the kernel of the action of $G$ by conjugation on $H$, and hence it is normal.